# Макросы в Microsoft Word на basic

Tags: ms-word, libre-office, basic

Помогите, пожалуйста, с заданием по макросам в Word или LibreOffice (Текстовый документ) на basic.

Задание: 
В каждом втором предложении поменять местами первое и последнее слово. Задать цвет этих слов в зависимости от количества букв (умножив соответственно на 20 и проверив на допустимость значения).

P.S: Я совершенно не разбираюсь в макросах.

Comment: Разберитесь и сделайте. Или заплатите денег фрилансерам и они сделают за вас, если вам разбираться не нужно.

Comment: Вы можете помочь разобраться?